# How to assign a JSON file as STEP in an EMR cluster in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I'm building an EMR cluster in Terraform and in the STEP argument i want to load a JSON file that describes the list of steps.

I tried this in my main.tf :

```
ressource "aws_emr" "emr" {
  ...
  ...
  step = "${data.template_file.steps.rendered}"
}

data "template_file" "steps" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/steps.json")}"
}
```

And this is the JSON file :

```
[
{
    "action_on_failure" : "CONTINUE",
    "name"              : "step_name",
    "hadoop_jar_step" : {
        "jar" : "command-runner.jar",
        "args" : [
            "spark-submit",
            "s3://mybucket/src/pyspark/script1.py",
            "1",
            "68465131321321",
            "s3://mybucket/parquet",
            "s3://mybucket/result",
            "321",
            "65165165468587",
            "654"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

But when i do `terraform plan` i got this error :

> Inappropriate value for attribute "step": list of object required.

What's the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the solution in another website and i'll post it here maybe it will help somebody oneday

```
   resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  ...
  dynamic "step" {
    for_each = jsondecode(templatefile("steps.json", {}))
    content {
      action_on_failure = step.value.action_on_failure
      name              = step.value.name
      hadoop_jar_step {
        jar  = step.value.hadoop_jar_step.jar
        args = step.value.hadoop_jar_step.args
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So that way it's possible to use a JSON file a source for the step in an EMR ressource.

Comment: What is the structure for the steps.json file?

Comment: Here is an example of a steps json file : 
https://jsonblob.com/1007d06f-111e-11ea-952e-a98fd6b9f322

Comment: Thanks; now I got it, it's further explained at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html

Answer (score 0):

Steps are not defined as JSON in the `aws_emr` resource, instead try:

```
step {
  action_on_failure = "CONTINUE"
  name              = "step_name"

  hadoop_jar_step {
    jar  = "command-runner.jar"
    args = ["spark-submit", ...]
  }
}
```

Comment: That way it woks, but i'm looking for a way to configure steps through a config file like a JSON file. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, the step is only defined as a `TypeList` in the AWS provider, there is no option for JSON in there. What you could do though is to use the new `jsondecode` function in terraform 0.12: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html. There are options in earlier versions as well, they do become a bit more hacky.

Comment: something like that  : step = jsondecode("${data.template_file.steps.rendered}") ?

Comment: Tried it but i got this error : Inappropriate value for attribute "step": element 0: attribute
"action_on_failure": string required.